# JQuery Multi-step form in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a multistep form wizard that go through seven(7) steps.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqHMU.png)

**Controllers:**

```
private RegistrationEntities db = new RegistrationEntities();
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

**View:**

```
  <div class="title_right">
      <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12 form-group pull-right top_search">
          <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
              </span>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>

     <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
               <div class="x_panel">
                    <div class="x_title">
                        <h2>Contractors <small>Pre-Registration</small></h2>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
                            <li>
                                <a class="collapse-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Settings 1</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Settings 2</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="close-link"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="x_content">
                        <p>Kindly Follow the Procedures for the Pre-Registration Process.</p>
                        <div id="wizard" class="form_wizard wizard_horizontal">
                            <ul class="wizard_steps">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#step-1">
                                        <span class="step_no">1</span>
                                        <span class="step_descr">
                                            Step 1<br />
                                            <small>Step 1: Ownership Confirmation</small>
                                        </span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#step-2">
                                        <span class="step_no">2</span>
                                        <span class="step_descr">
                                            Step 2<br />
                                            <small>Step 2: RC Number</small>
                                        </span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#step-3">
                                        <span class="step_no">3</span>
                                        <span class="step_descr">
                                            Step 3<br />
                                            <small>Step 3: Company Name</small>
                                        </span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#step-4">
                                        <span class="step_no">4</span>
                                        <span class="step_descr">
                                            Step 4<br />
                                            <small>Step 4: TIN Number/Company Details</small>
                                        </span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#step-5">
                                        <span class="step_no">5</span>
                                        <span class="step_descr">
                                            Step 5<br />
                                            <small>Step 5: Company's Email</small>
                                        </span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#step-6">
                                        <span class="step_no">6</span>
                                        <span class="step_descr">
                                            Step 6<br />
                                            <small>Step 6: Other Company Details</small>
                                        </span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#step-7">
                                        <span class="step_no">7</span>
                                        <span class="step_descr">
                                            Step 7<br />
                                            <small>Step 7: Captcha</small>
                                        </span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <div id="step-1">
                                <form class="form-horizontal form-label-left">

                                    <div class="form-group">

                                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                                            <div class="col-lg-3">
                                                <div class="form-group">

                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <div class="radio">
                                                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.OWNERSHIP_STRUCTURE, 1, new { @class = "DoPopup", id = "Foreign Company", value = "" }) Foreign Company
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="radio">
                                                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.OWNERSHIP_STRUCTURE, 2, new { @class = "DoPopup", id = "Foreign Owned Nigerian Company", value = "" }) Foreign Owned Nigerian Company
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="radio">
                                                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.OWNERSHIP_STRUCTURE, 3, new { @class = "DoPopup", id = "Nigerian Company", value = "" }) Nigerian Company
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-3">
                                                <div class="form-group">

                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        </div>
                            </form>
                            </div>

                            <div id="step-2">
                                @*<h2 class="StepTitle">Step 2 Content</h2>*@
                                <form class="form-horizontal form-label-left">
                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RC_NUMBER, new { @class = "col-lg-2 control-label" })
                                            <div class="col-lg-9">
                                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RC_NUMBER, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RC_NUMBER)
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>

                            </div>
                            <div id="step-3">
                                @*<h2 class="StepTitle">Step 3 Content</h2>*@
                                <form class="form-horizontal form-label-left">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.COMPANY_NAME, new { @class = "col-lg-2 control-label" })
                                                <div class="col-lg-9">
                                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.COMPANY_NAME, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.COMPANY_NAME)
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            <div id="step-5">
                                <form class="form-horizontal form-label-left">
                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.COMPANY_CONTACT_EMAIL, new { @class = "col-lg-2 control-label" })
                                            <div class="col-lg-9">
                                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.COMPANY_CONTACT_EMAIL, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.COMPANY_CONTACT_EMAIL)
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            <div id="step-6">
                                <form class="form-horizontal form-label-left">
                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-lg-2">
                                                Alternative E-mail
                                            </div>                                                
                                            <div class="col-lg-9">
                                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.COMPANY_CONTACT_ALTERNATIVE_EMAIL, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.COMPANY_CONTACT_ALTERNATIVE_EMAIL)
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-lg-2">
                                                Website
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-9">
                                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.WEBSITE, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.WEBSITE)
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <h3>Login Details</h3>
                                    <hr />

                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                        <div class="col-lg-1">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-lg-2">
                                                Username
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-8">
                                                @*<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>*@
                                                <input class="form-control input-lg" name="MERGE0" id="email" type="email" placeholder="Email address" required>
                                            </div>
                                         </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-1">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                        <div class="col-lg-1">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-lg-2">
                                                Password
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-8">
                                                @*<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>*@
                                                <input class="form-control input-lg" name="MERGE1" id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-1">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                        </form>
                            </div>

                            <div id="step-7">
                                <form class="form-horizontal form-label-left">
                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                        <div class="col-lg-1">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                @Html.MathCaptcha()

                                              @*  @Html.Captcha(3)*@
                                                <br />
                                                <p class="Error">  @ViewBag.ErrMessage </p> 
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-1">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                 </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

}

```js
    <!-- jQuery Smart Wizard -->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#wizard').smartWizard();

        $('#wizard_verticle').smartWizard({
            transitionEffect: 'slide'
        });

        $('.buttonNext').addClass('btn btn-success');
        $('.buttonPrevious').addClass('btn btn-primary');
        $('.buttonFinish').addClass('btn btn-default');
    });
</script>
<!-- /jQuery Smart Wizard -->
```

The questions are:

1. How I I validate each step to make sure values are entered befor going to the next step
2. After completing the 7 steps, how do I valid that the values are entered properly before it saves.
3. After completing the 7th step, I clicked on the Finish button, no record was saved into the CONTRACTORS table
4. In step2, when RC_NUMBER is entered, it should check if it already exists. It should use it to populate COMPANY_NAME in step3, but if it doesnt exist, it should allow the user to enter COMPANY_NAME in step3
5. After completing the whole steps and Finish button is clicked, it should redirect to welcome model using ActionResult Welcome

Answer (score 0):

Please check the answers to your questions below:

1.) jQuery SmartWizard allows us to add `onLeaveStep:leaveAStepCallback` field while declaring. `leaveAStepCallback` is the function that will be called when you click on the next button. You can implement your validation logic in this function. Please go through [this](https://github.com/mstratman/jQuery-Smart-Wizard/blob/master/README.md#input-validation) URL to get the complete idea.

2.) jQuery SmartWizard also allows us to add `onFinish:onFinishCallback` field while declaring. In this case `onFinishCallback` function will be called after all the steps are completed. You can check here if all the inputs are valid and then submit the form. You must have got the idea if you had gone through the link in answer 1.

3.) You need to further elaborate why the details were not saved in DB? Is your controller action getting called? If yes, check your DB save logic to further find the issue as this is not the issue of SmartWizard.

4.) As I mentioned in the step 1 that bind a callback function to be called when next button is clicked. In this function, you can get the step number by using `context.fromStep`. After that you can make an ajax call to server to check if the value already exist. Implement your custom logic as required.

5.) If you are submitting form using `$('form').submit()`, you can redirect custom view from the controller after succesful operation. If you are making an ajax call, redirect to another controller in `sucess` function of ajax call.